# Debugging Gate-level Verilog Multiplexer

Tags: verilog, debugging

I've built a 4-1 multiplexer using three 2-1 multiplexers, but am having a lot of trouble debugging my code. I've tried using `$display` statements as rudimentary debugging methods, but it doesn't seem to be helping. Here is my code:

```
module multiplex4_to_1(S, C, O); //S[0] is and, S[1] is or
    input [3:0] S;               //S[2] is add, S[3] is less
    input [1:0] C;               //C[0] picks and/or + add/less
                                 //C[1] picks m1 or m2
    output O;

    wire m1_out, m2_out;


    multiplex m1(S[1], S[0], C[0], m1_out),
              m2(S[3], S[2], C[0], m2_out),
              m3(m2_out, m1_out, C[1], O);

endmodule

module multiplex(A, B, C, D);
   input A, B, C;
   output D;

   wire x, y, z;

   not n1(x, A);

   and a1(y, A, C),
       a2(z, x, B);
   or o1(D, z, y);

endmodule
```

My test bench is:

```
module test_adder;
   reg [3:0] S;
   reg [1:0] C;

   wire O;
   multiplex4_to_1 m(S, C, O);
   initial
     begin
       $monitor("%b %b %b %b OUTPUT: %b", S[3], S[2], S[1], S[0], O);
       S = 4'b0011; C = 2'b01;
       #1 S = 4'b0001; C = 2'b01;
       #1 S = 4'b0010; C = 2'b01;
     end
endmodule
```

The 2-1 multiplexer works just fine, but it seems that when I put them together, something breaks.

The expected output would be the two, given a `C = 2'b01'`, it would output `S[0]`. The least significant bit of `C` chooses between both `S[0:1]` and `S[2:3]`, and `C[1]` chooses between these two options.

The output for the above code is

```
0 0 1 1 OUTPUT: 1
0 0 0 1 OUTPUT: 1
0 0 1 0 OUTPUT: 1
```

But I expect:

```
0 0 1 1 OUTPUT: 1
0 0 0 1 OUTPUT: 0
0 0 1 0 OUTPUT: 1
```

Comment: It helps to explain what you expected to see, versus what you actually saw,

Comment: I tried to add some clarification at the end.

Comment: And what are you seeing instead

Comment: Edited again with current output, and expected output.

Comment: A note on style: For your sake and others', use more descriptive names. Why "A, B, C, D" over "In0, In1, Sel, Out"? If the 4-to-1 mux is a mux, why are its inputs called "S" and "C"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If A and B are your inputs which C selects from (judging by your 4-to-1 mux pin order), your 2-to-1 mux is definitely wrong. Your output D is $$D = \bar{A}B+AC$$ Your output D is true for A=0, B=1 regardless of C. That's not correct.